# MongoError: authentication or logout allready in process

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

im getting this exception sometimes when im loading my server app,
I think it might be some race-condition? because it won't happen all the times.
Might it be related to the fact I have few instance of moongose DB connection?
via different schema files
Thanks for the help !

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var url="...";
mongoose.connect(url);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

// create a schema
var PostSchema = new Schema({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  title: String,
  postData: { type: String, required: true }
});

var PostManager = mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema);

module.exports = PostManager;
```

> Exception: C:\matan
>   project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
>       process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                                     ^ MongoError: authentication or logout allready in process
>       at ReplSet.auth (C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:1181:21)
>       at ReplSet.auth (C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\replset.js:481:23)
>       at authenticate (C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\authenticate.js:64:21)
>       at Db.module.exports (C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\authenticate.js:91:44)
>       at Db.authenticate (C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1487:23)
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:719:14)
>       at C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:683:11
>       at C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:217:5
>       at C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:238:5
>       at ReplSet.connectHandler (C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\replset.js:343:7)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>       at ReplSet.emit (events.js:210:7)
>       at C:\matan project\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:728:20
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting
>   for file changes before starting...

Comment: where is the url for `var url` ??

Comment: i deleted it for the post..